# Attributed text not displaying in emulator device

Tags: ios, xcode

I was using the attributed text to edit the style of string in the text. In the storyboard, it display exact what I want.  But when I try to run the app to emulator device to see if the result look good but attributed text was not displaying.  The emulator device only display plain text.  How can I make the emulator device to display attributed text?

```
<!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Hfg-vx-s6i">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="di3-Y9-W12" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="F6t-h3-SiZ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="axk-bq-fyl"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ph9-HP-KWx">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" usesAttributedText="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pNn-mb-lpY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="240" height="128"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <attributedString key="attributedText">
                                    <fragment content="This is test and this suppose to be bold.">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue-Bold"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                    <fragment content="          ">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                    <fragment content="This is test and this suppose to be italic.">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue-Italic"/>
                                            <font key="NSOriginalFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue-Italic"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                    <fragment content="          ">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                    <fragment content="This is test and this suppose to be regular.">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue"/>
                                            <font key="NSOriginalFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                    <fragment content="          Test Test Test">
                                        <attributes>
                                            <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="HelveticaNeue"/>
                                            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
                                        </attributes>
                                    </fragment>
                                </attributedString>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" fixedFrame="YES">
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="400" height="800"/>
                                </variation>
                            </textView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <variation key="default">
                            <mask key="subviews">
                                <exclude reference="pNn-mb-lpY"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                        <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact">
                            <mask key="subviews">
                                <include reference="pNn-mb-lpY"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
```

Comment: Here is the code. In my storyboard, I can see bold, italic.  But in emulator device, I only see plain text.

Comment: can you make sure that devices have those fonts ? can you try to create the same font from code and log it ? or just log the font and attributed string of the label

Comment: I tried different font such as Time New Roman, Verdana. But the result still remain the same.

Comment: but, I am not sure what do you mean by create the same font from code and log it?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@ - %@",self.label.font,self.label.attributedText);

and

UIFont *font = [UIFont withname:fontname];
NSLog(@"%@",font");

Comment: Where do I put these code in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was the solution to that problem but I uncheck the size classes in file inspector and all of device was able to show the attributed texts.  I don't know why it is happening but it is working.

[image]

Thank you for trying solve this.